# Перенос данных между базами данных

Tags: sql, mysql

Всем добрый день, столкнулся с необходимостью залить данные из одной базы в другую, притом структура баз разная. Как это делать? Понимаю, что инсертами с селектами, но поточнее? Вот так я пытался делать у себя на тестовой базе, в консоли системы:

```
 mysql -u root -p INSERT INTO test.dar_artist('name', 'photo', 'about') VALUES SELECT name, image, content FROM dar_db.artists_artist;
```

Здесь test - новая база, куда нужно вставить данные, а dar_db - старая база, с данными, которые нужно выдрать. Однако консоль ругается на

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Понимаю, что где-то мелкая ошибка, но где? Подскажите :)

**Добавлено:**
Неправильно делал выполнение команды в консоли, ошибка баш исчезла, делаю сейчас вот так:

```
mysql -u root -proot -e "INSERT INTO test.dar_artist('name', 'photo', 'about') VALUES SELECT name, image, content FROM dar_db.artists_artist";
```

Теперь мускул ругается на неверный синтаксис... Кавычки и values пробовал - всё равно ероры =\

**Добавлено**
Чёрт, я в шоке... Убрал values по совету [[@renegator](/users/2283/renegator)](/users/2283/renegator) - всё равно ошибки. Поменял столбцы местами - ошибки пропали! Дурдом... Вот код, который работает:

```
mysql -u root -proot -e "insert into test.dar_artist(name, about, photo) select name, content, image from dar_db.artists_artist;"
```

Comment: Либо вы приводите не те данные, либо у вас кривой шел.
Покажите скриншот с выполненным запросом и ошибке

Comment: Скриншот уже не покажу - дело давно сделано и база залита.  
Как я указал во втором дополнении в своём вопросе - всего лишь поменял местами столбцы(попарно) и всё заработало. Т.е. сперва было  

    "INSERT INTO test.dar_artist('name', 'photo', 'about') SELECT name, image, content FROM dar_db.artists_artist;"#Выкидывало ошибку синтаксиса
А вот так заработало без ошибок:  

    "insert into test.dar_artist(name, about, photo) select name, content, image from dar_db.artists_artist;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VALUES убрать

Comment: Всё равно  

    bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Да уберите values уже: запрос же вставляется.

    mysql -u root -proot -e "INSERT INTO test.dar_artist('name', 'photo', 'about') SELECT name, image, content FROM dar_db.artists_artist"

Comment: Ошибка синтаксиса. Думаете я не пробовал без values? Как бы не так... :(

Answer (score 1):

Так у меня работает:

```
mysql -uroot -e "INSERT INTO test2.c(id) SELECT id FROM test1.a";
```

Comment: Походу у меня ероры со вставкой нескольких значений через values().. Что-то не вкуриваю, как правильно синтаксис записать - вроде по мануалам делаю =\

Comment: Обычный селект у меня тоже работает, с одним полем)

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки не те - используйте косые.

Comment: Разницы в кавычках нет - всё равно та же ошибка. bash - это консоль системы, а не мускула, и этот bash ругается...(

Comment: INSERT INTO `test`.`dar_artist`(`name`, `photo`, `about`) VALUES (SELECT `name`, `image`, `content` FROM `dar_db`.`artists_artist`)

Так пробовали?

Comment: Только что - чёртовы ероры... :(

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, Вы разобрались, в чем была ошибка? Смотрел пример в комментариях в [официальном учебнике MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

> Posted by Haakon Meland Eriksen on September 28 2004 6:18am    [Delete] [Edit]
>
> Using INSERT INTO ... SELECT you can copy data from one database to another. You need the correct privileges for both.
>
> Enter the source database, database1:
>
> `use database1;`
>
> Then write to which fields in the destination database you want to copy to, database2:
>
> `INSERT INTO database2.table1 (field1,field3,field9)
> SELECT table2.field3,table2.field1,table2.field4
> FROM table2;`
>
> The order of the selected fields and the inserted fields must match, so you enter the correct data. Before doing this, use "describe database2.table1" and "describe database1.table2", to make sure the new fields can hold the same kind of information.

Обратите внимание, как он поступает - активирует базу, из которой будет копировать, и потом производит копирование соответствующих полей... Вы так не пробовали?

Comment: USE только переключает контекст пользователя на базу. Однако, если в запросе объекты заданы полностью - с указанием имени базы данных, то безразлично, в контексте какой базы он выполняется

Comment: Я выполнял код не из консоли мускула, а из консоли системы, везде указывались названия баз данных, поэтому в этом нет смысла(в моём контексте).